# What is the function of "none" in "mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug"?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, mount

From [debugfs.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/debugfs.txt), mount `debugfs` command is like this:

```
mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug
```

What is the function of `none` in this statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That argument is a description of the device to be mounted. Typically this is a filename like `/dev/sda1`, but for mounts not associated with a device you can use an arbitrary name. `none` is just a conventional choice, you could just as easily use `bacon` or `this_is_not_the_device_you_are_looking_for`.

Comment: IOW, it's just a placeholder since it will be ignored anyway during `mount()` system call.